# How to get coordinates with decimals

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates

I'm trying to improve a script and to that I have to get points coordinates. I found a way to do this with these few lines:

```
layer = processing.getObject(point)
iter1 = layer.getFeatures()
for feature1 in iter1:
        x = feature1.geometry().asPoint().x()
        y = feature1.geometry().asPoint().y()
        print "X Coord : %d" %x
        print "Y Coord : %d" %y
        print
```

But it returns coordinates without decimals, like this (Lambert 93):

```
X Coord : 694752 
Y Coord : 6244790
```

Somebody have an idea to get decimals ?

Comment: Your code probably works correctly, you only have an issue with the `print` function (you're trying to print integers). Try to use `%f` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Ahah ! exactly !! `print` is just a test  for me to see if it works correctly. So `x` and `y` contains coordinates with decimals. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code probably works correctly, you only have an issue with the `print` function (you're trying to print integers). Try to use `%f` instead of `%d`.